# Exponential distribution as limiting distribution

Tags: probability, soft-question, probability-distributions

I wonder if there are well-known and studied cases involving Exponential distribution as limiting distribution. I also wonder if this would contradict Central Limit theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since exponential distribution is a special case of [Weibull distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), and that arises as a limit distribution in [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) (see [Gnedenko-Fisher-Tippet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem)).

For example, consider a uniform (on a unit interval) sample of size $n$. Then
$$
   \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\left( \min(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n) \leqslant \frac{x}{n}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1- \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n = 1 - \exp(-x)
$$
The latter is exactly the CDF of the exponential random variable with unit mean.

This does not contradict the CLT as the latter does not apply for this case.